# Web Push Notifications using AWS IOT and SNS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, push-notification, amazon-sns, aws-iot

I want to implement a common push notification service for WEB and mobile. I found that AWS IOT can be used to implement PUSH Services as mentioned in this link: https://serverless.zone/iot-with-the-serverless-framework-e228fae87be but it's not using SNS anyhow.

Now, If I come separately on AWS-SNS, it's home page claims that it should be used for push notifications (https://aws.amazon.com/sns/), but as per my reading, we will still need GCM for android in between. Then why should we use SNS at all? And what do we need for WEB in such cases?

Which one should we use AWS IOT or SNS for push notifications? and how should it be implemented?